# Script working fine from command line, but not from crontab

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, cron

My crontab entry as "ins" user is this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/ksh /apps/swbkp/swbkp.sh
```

The script is:

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh

. /apps/ins/.profile

cdate=$(date +'%y%m%d')

/apps/omni/bin/swmml -e "backup-node:" >> /apps/swbkp/swerrr1.$cdate

#
if [[ -f /apps/omni/conf/archive.C7M3UAA.500.$cdate ]]
then
   mv -f /apps/omni/conf/archive.C7M3UAA.500.$cdate /apps/swbkp/
elif [[ -f /apps/omni/labeir1/dffile/archive.C7M3UAA.500.$cdate ]]
then
   mv -f /apps/omni/labeir1/dffile/archive.C7M3UAA.500.$cdate /apps/swbkp/
else
   printf "Backup archive File not present to move"
fi >> /apps/swbkp/swerrr1.$cdate
#
```

Note: `/apps/omni/bin/swmml -e "backup-node:"` this line simply creates a backup file on my system of type `archive.C7M3UA.500.<current date>`

2 weird things happening:

1. the backup file generated is:

   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 165 Aug 28 21:55 /apps/omni/labeir1/dffile/archive.C7M3UAA.500.130828

When getting moved to `/apps/swbkp`, the timestamp is 1 min before:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  165 Aug 28 21:54 archive.C7M3UAA.500.130828
```

1. Nothing is getting redirected to `/apps/swbkp/swerrr1.$cdate` file

   -rw-r--r-- 1 ins  ins     0 Aug 28 21:24 swerrr1.130828

Whereas when I run the script from terminal, everything works perfect, i.e the file has the same timestamp in backup folder as well as moved folder, and outputs are getting logged in the log file as well.

Kindly help

Comment: It seems like something else is writing to this file `/apps/omni/labeir1/dffile/archive.C7M3UAA.500.130828` while it is getting moved. I would do a `md5` check between the two. Nothing will be redirected because it is not reaching the final `else` condition.

Comment: @iamauser no , the script when run standalone, gives a "backup completed" message which gets redirected to the log file, this only doesn't happen from crontab

Answer (score 1):

This may already have been answered, but for anyone looking for help:

You'll need to escape the 'percent' like below when using date/time stamps in crons:

`cdate=$(date +'\%y\%m\%d') instead of cdate=$(date +'%y%m%d')`

if using this in yaml/ Ansible playbooks, you'll need to double escape or escape the escape like:

`$(date +'\\%y\\%m\\%d')`

Eventually the cron should look something like

`* * * * * script.sh > /tmp/script_$(date +\%y\%m\%d).log 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `/apps/ins/.profile` and the files it executes - such files usually have a conditional that exits the script early if it's not run in a terminal.

For example:

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

This may change the behavior of your script (or even skip it, if `exit` is used in place of `return`). At the very least, you will miss aliases, possible PATH changes, and other things set up in the `.profile` script, which will affect if and how your main script is run.

Try to comment the line `. /apps/ins/.profile` in the script above, and see if it still runs in the terminal. If it does, run it like that from crontab and see if it fixes your problem.